# App not receiving VOIP after x time on iOS 10.3 >

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, ios10.3, pushkit

I've got a project I'm working on which uses VOIP notifications to "wake up" apps that have been put into background/terminated. These notifications are sent periodically, and everything seemed to work fine until recent iOS updates.

It appears that after a certain amount of time in which the app has been in the background (happens to some users after 5 minutes, others after 20), the devices no longer process any code after receiving the voip notifications.

I've read a bit in apple dev forums and some other devs are running into similar issues, all speculate if its related to the new iOS updates (10.3.1/10.3.2).

Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, have you been able to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! did you find solution? how did you fix it?

Comment: Have you found any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is the new normal on latest iOS versions.

You should begin to use push notifications.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html) is a guide from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up seeming to be the fix was updating to a newer version of `socketio` library.

Answer (score -1):

You can try debugging your app in background or in kill state ( terminated state ), so you can get to know that payload from pushkit comes or not or possibly some crash at iOS code end.

**Debug pushkit notification in terminated state**

- Put debug pointer on delegate methods
- Go to edit scheme
- Select run option then Launch -> Wait for executable to be launched
- Send push kit payload from back end
- Once you get payload on device
- it will automatically invoke and debug pointer will invoke at delegate methods.

[image]

[Refer](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)